# C++ DOXYGEN ATRTRIBUTE defined by macro

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

I have an ATTRIBUTES defined by macros. 
Is it posible for doxygen to put them in the Attributes section and be displayed seam as normal Attributes? (not in function)

```
#define DEF_ATRTRIBUTE(_Name, _Type, _LowerLimit, _UpperLimit, _Data, _Description)
```

It is necessary because of the complexity of the code...

```
DEF_ATRTRIBUTE(MyVar, ui8, 0, 255, 8, "example")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Doxygen doesn't have a preprocessor and hence can't resolve macros correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen is not designed specifically for C/C++ and does not include C/C++ macro preprocessor. It works with your source code.

But what you can do is to use your C/C++ compiler to generate preprocessed code (i.e. source with macros expanded) and give that source to Doxygen as input.

You didn't tell what compiler you are using. For Visual Studio compiler it is [/P switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx), for others - look for their documentation